# Are there any other types of non-euclidean geometry?

Tags: geometry, soft-question, noneuclidean-geometry

We have 2 non-euclidean geometries(ie. **not satisfying the fifth postulate** ) in hand. But can there be some other models of non-euclidean geometries different from the known two?

In other words, do the other axioms of Euclid enforce the number of  lines parallel to a given line and passing through a given point to be 0,1 or $\infty$?

Comment: Short short answer: yes, but I don't recall the proof offhand - I'll have to do a little digging. I think the loose outline is that one can formulate enough of 'betweenness' that once you have two lines through a given point not intersecting a third line, you can talk about the pencil of lines 'between' these two lines, show that none of them intersect the third line, and show that there are infinitely many of them. (Or at least a continuum of them - note that Euclidean geometry itself doesn't speak of 'infinity', so specifically formulating this idea is tricky)

Comment: Thanks! Please get me a reference....@ Steven Stadnicki

Comment: Talking out of my hat I'm thinking that symmetry and generality make these  and maybe a geometry with a finite number of points the only options.  Just talking out of my hat.  Digging deeper into my hat I think you can create a hokey derivative geometry non-symmetric geometry where some lines have infinite parallel lines, some 27 and some 3 but I think those are trivial and futile subcases of "real" geometries.  Or... I don't know.

Comment: hyperbolic is infinite.  As the op clearly stated.  There are three well known geometries with 0, 1, and infinite.  The op is asking if there can be others.  Intuitively by the basic ideas of congruence anything about a line and a point can be applied to any other line and point and the basic idea of "completeness" any distance or measure can be represented, I think intuitively these are the only three options.  one point has $\alpha$ parallel lines, all point will have the same.  If there are two parallel lines there's a continuum of parallel lines between them.